# Java mysql Error: Could not find or load main class lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar

Tags: java, mysql

**My screen:**

[image: http://gyazo.com/b5e94029c8356c693f8ce51bed98f97a.png]

---

**And Lib folder:**

[image: http://gyazo.com/a521f4b3bf3b1623fd3cc2ec6aa94705.png]

This is my run.bat:

```
@echo off
title Tracer
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\java"  -Xmx256m -cp bin; lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar Mains
pause
```

Mains.java is located in src, and is findable.

***What is the problem?, Trying to install mysql for the first time!***

Answer (score 1):

Your `-cp` argument needs to be without spaces.  Change

```
-cp bin; lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar
```

to

```
-cp bin;lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar
```

The error message indicated that your class path was treated as just "bin;" and the other part (the path to the jar) was treated as the class to run.

Shells and the Windows command prompt usually treat spaces as separators between arguments, which is why removing the space is recommended here.

Comment: Worked, thanks a lot. Is there a need to include Xmx at all for a small program?

Comment: That I don't know; I just saw the space error in the classpath argument.

Comment: Martin, probably not, though, unless you're running a relatively crappy computer, it shouldn't make much of a difference.